Best practice: type-bound procedure or select type?
when extending types, I sometimes hesitate between writing type-bound procedures for each type or writing a single procedure that uses select type blocks.
I've always wondered whether, in such cases, it's simply a matter of "style" or if one of these solutions is more efficient, and whether there is a 'best practice' rule that could be followed in code design.
The opinion of experts would be very helpful to me.
Here are minimalist examples to make clearer if necessary:
module fooVersion1_m
   type :: base_t
      !...
   contains
      procedure, pass :: dosomething => dosomething_for_base
      !...
   end type base_t

   type, extends(base_t) :: typ1_t
      !...
   contains
      procedure, pass :: dosomething => dosomething_for_typ1
      !...
   end type typ1_t

contains
   subroutine dosomething_for_base ( self )
      class(base_t), intent(inout) :: self
      print*,'do some thing for base_t'
      !...
   end subroutine dosomething_for_base

   subroutine dosomething_for_typ1 ( self )
      class(typ1_t), intent(inout) :: self
      print*,'do some thing for typ1_t'
      !...
   end subroutine dosomething_for_typ1
end module fooVersion1_m

program foo
use fooVersion1_m
type(base_t) :: a
type(typ1_t) :: b

call a%dosomething
call b%dosomething

end program foo

module fooVersion2_m
   type :: base_t
     !...
   contains
     !...
   end type base_t

   type, extends(base_t) :: typ1_t
     !...
   contains
     !...
   end type typ1_t

contains
   subroutine dosomething ( a )
      class(base_t), intent(in out) :: a
      select type ( a )
      type is ( base_t )
         print*,'do some thing for base_t'
         !...
      type is ( typ1_t )
         print*,'do some thing for typ1_t'
         !...
      end select
   end subroutine dosomething
end module fooVersion2_m

program foo
use fooVersion2_m
type(base_t) :: a
type(typ1_t) :: b

call dosomething(a)
call dosomething(b)

end program foo


It depends on if you're an object-oriented or procedural person :)... I can see a drawback of the select type approach if the routines are repeatedly called, with a low workload in each call: in this case the overhead of the select type may hurt the performances.

Type bound almost every time, it's just cleaner to my eye. But that's just my opinion

Again a question that is closed with a bad reason. The question looks like opinion-based but it's not, at least if one reads carefully. And the answer (as well as my own comment above) are not just opinions, they are based on technical facts.

One of the big points of polymorphism is that the user of your module may want to extend the type with another type that is not known at the time of writing your module. They can write they own version of the subroutine for that extended type and it will be selected at runtime using dynamic dispatch.
That cannot be done with select type, that is purely static manual dispatch.

Thank thank you for your feedback.
My hesitation stems from the multiplication of procedures to write (and their interfaces when using submodules). I'm probably a bit too lazy.
